# Trying to import a script from other code

Tags: python, import

I need help to import a script, i did 2 codes, the first is a test with some prints and in the second i try to import them:

**Code 1**

```
# I make some print's to try import and show if it works

def first():
    print('Test')


class phrase:
    def second():
        print('Hello')

    def third():
        print('World')
```

**Code 2**

```
import os

attempt = os.system(r"python C:\Users\Gabri\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Imagens.py")

# Obviously isn't works =(
attempt.first()
```

But in code 2, when i did `os.system(r"python C:\Users\Gabri\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Imagens.py")` nothing happen.
Someone can help me to import this code? ;-;

> 1° Code is in C:\Users\Gabri\PycharmProjects\pythonProject

> 2° in C:\Users\Gabri\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Prática\Vamove

Comment: Python documentation has a section on modules and how to import them into your code. Take a look here. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html. Also in your question you don't tell us what the file names are. Python uses file names and directory names for importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the files where they are,
You should by able to do this:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
    "name", "C:\\Users\\Gabri\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\Imagens.py")
Imagens = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(Imagens)
```

And then run your commands like this:

```
Imagens.first()
```

Comment: I run your code and this happen ```NameError: name 'foo' is not defined``` what's 'foo'?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I fixed the code. It should work now

Comment: Forgets, i just add ```.third()``` to ```Imagens.phrase``` and it worked hahaha

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is if you put both in the same folder and make that folder a python directory from which you can import your other code as modules. All you need for that is a file in the folder containing a blank `__init__.py` file. Then you can import it to another code file in the same folder using

`from folder_name import Imagens`

and you should be able to use Imagens functions like any other module

Ex: `Imagens.first()`